# Complexity of a satisfaction relation

Tags: logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Given $x, y \in \omega^\omega$, we may define an expanded structure $(\mathbb{N}, x, y)$ where $x,y$ are treated as interpretations of function symbols. I want to show that there is a computable set $P \subseteq \omega^{<\omega} \times \omega^{<\omega} \times \omega^{<\omega}$ such that

$\forall x \in \omega^{\omega} \exists y \in \omega^{\omega}  (\mathbb{N}, x, y) \vDash \sigma \iff \forall x \in \omega^{\omega} \exists y \in \omega^{\omega} \forall n \in \omega P(x_{|n}, y_{|n})$

This is an important intermediary step in proving (a version of) the Schoenfield Absoluteness theorem. To be clear, I don't want a proof of the Schoenfield absoluteness theorem. I'm curious about this in particular.

I imagine $P$ has to do with the recursive definition of the $\vDash$ relation, but I'm not sure I can completely see it. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: What is $\sigma$, some arbitrary sentence?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is. $\sigma$ is a sentence of arbitrary complexity in the language of $(\mathbb{N}, x, y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To clarify, the actual structure in question - per the comments below - is $\mathcal{N}_{x,y}:=(\mathbb{N};+,\times,<,x,y)$ or something "morally equivalent" to that (e.g. it's fine if we drop "$<$"). Weakening the language doesn't make the left-to-right direction any harder of course, but it may make the right-to-left direction **false**.*

---

The right-to-left direction is vastly easier: it basically amounts to the fact that computable relations are definable in $(\mathbb{N};+,\times,<)$. So I'll ignore it here and focus on the interesting part, the left-to-right direction.

The left-to-right direction is rather tedious to write out in full, but the key ideas aren't too hard. This answer is really just a hint for the left-to-right direction but I think it does extract those key ideas, and will make the full solution much simpler to understand. Specifically, I'll indicate how to solve a "toy version" of the actual problem which, while substantially simpler, still in my opinion will clarify the idea.

Below I've written out my rationale for the choice of problem; if you just want to dive in, skip to the subsequent section.

---

First, I'm going to make a seemingly-trivial change to the desired property of $P$ in question: $$\forall x \in \omega^{\omega} \exists y \in \omega^{\omega}  \mathcal{N}_{x,y} \vDash \sigma \iff \forall x \in \omega^{\omega} \exists \color{red}{z} \in \omega^{\omega} \forall n \in \omega P(x_{|n}, z_{|n}).$$ I want to change the variable name because this $z$ should **not** be thought of as serving the role of $y$ in the left hand side. Instead, $z$ contains a lot more information. Specifically, **and this is the absolutely key idea**, we'll think of the desired $z$ as being the "join" of two reals $a,b\in\omega^\omega$ where $a$ is a real such that $\mathcal{N}_{x,a}\models \sigma$ and $b$ is a real *witnessing that fact* in a precise sense to be developed below.

- There are a few different ways to define the join of two reals; it doesn't matter which we use, but for concreteness I'll set $a\oplus b:=(\langle a_i,b_i\rangle)_{i\in\omega}$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the Cantor pairing function and for $u\in \omega^\omega$ we write "$u_i$" for the $i$th bit of $u$. The point is that we can clearly "extract" $a$ and $b$ from $a\oplus b$.

Second, I want to replace *computability* with *topology*. This is often a useful simplifying step, under the slogan "computable = effectively tame" for tame $\in\{$ continuous, closed, ...$\}$ - in this case, tame=closed. (The converse is also often useful, e.g. in the proof of the Harrington-Kechris-Louveau theorem, but not relevant right now.)

Finally, I want to fix a specific $\sigma$ which will be easier to work with - I'll use the sentence $$\sigma\equiv\forall m\exists n>n(x_n<y_n),$$ often abbreviated as "$y$ *escapes* $x$." This is just a very simple sentence to think about, while not being totally trivial.

---

So with all that, here's the "toy version" of the original problem:

> Show that there is a closed set $\mathfrak{Q}\subseteq(\omega^\omega)^2$ such that $$\forall x \in \omega^{\omega} \exists y \in \omega^{\omega}  \mathcal{N}_{x,y} \models \forall m\exists n>m(x_m<y_m) \quad\iff\quad \forall x \in \omega^{\omega} \exists z \in \omega^{\omega} (\langle x,z\rangle\in\mathfrak{Q}).$$

The point of looking at this toy version first is that it lets us focus on the actually "deep" part of the problem: **witnessing satisfaction by reals**. Fixing reals $x$ and $y$, what does it mean for one real $w$ to witness the fact that $\mathcal{N}_{x,y}\models \forall m\exists n>m(x_n<y_n)$?

Well, think of a witness as a way of **convincing** me that the given statement holds. The way you'd do this is provide me with a rule giving an appropriate $n$ for each $m$. Now it's too much to hope for an actual rule-rule, but we can "bundle up" all the individual $m$-cases into a single real: for appropriate $x$ and $y$, we'll say $w$ **witnesses** $\mathcal{N}_{x,y}\models\sigma$ iff for each $i\in\omega$ we have $w_i>i$ and $x_{w_i}<y_{w_i}$.

Taking the idea from the start of this answer, this suggests looking at the following set. First, let $p_0,p_1$ be the projection maps coming from the Cantor pairing function, so that for all $l\in\omega$ we have $l=\langle p_{left}(l), p_{right}(l)\rangle$. Next, let $\mathbb{p}_{left},\mathbb{p}_{right}:\omega^\omega\rightarrow\omega^\omega$ be their "bitwise" analogues for reals, so that for each $c\in\omega^\omega$ we have $c_i=\langle \mathbb{p}_{left}(c)_i, \mathbb{p}_{right}(c)_i \rangle$. We then want to look at: $$\mathfrak{Q}=\{\langle x,z\rangle: (\mathbb{p}_{right}(z)\mbox{ witnesses }\mathcal{N}_{x,\mathbb{p}_{left}(z)}\models\forall m\exists n>m(x_n<\mathbb{p}_{left}(z)_n))\}.$$

- Keep in mind that $\mathbb{p}_{left}(z)$ is an element of $\omega^\omega$, so $\mathbb{p}_{left}(z)_n$ is that element's $n$th "bit."

Now on the face of things that doesn't look like a closed set, but you can rewrite it:

> The pair $\langle x,z\rangle$ is in $\mathfrak{Q}$ iff $\forall k\in\omega$ we have $$x_{\mathbb{p}_{right}(z)_k}<(\mathbb{p}_{left}(z))_{\mathbb{p}_{right}(z)_k}.$$ That is, $\mathbb{p}_{right}(z)_k$ tells us a term which is sufficiently large and at which $x$ is less than $\mathbb{p}_{left}(z)$.

Using this rewriting, it's not hard to show that $\mathfrak{Q}$ is closed. *(HINT: supposing $\langle x,z\rangle\not\in\mathfrak{Q}$, find some $j$ such that there is no pair of reals $x', z'$ extending $x_{\vert j}, z_{\vert j}$ respectively with $\langle x',z'\rangle\in\mathfrak{Q}$; this will say that $\mathfrak{Q}$'s complement is open.)*

---

We now have to switch from topology back to computability, and generalize to arbitrary $\sigma$.

The computability/topology shift is pretty easy to undo, and goes the same for every $\sigma$: you just have to show that there is some computable relation $Q\subseteq(\omega^{<\omega})^2$ corresponding to our closed set $\mathfrak{Q}$, that is, some computable relation $Q$ such that for all $u,v$ we have $$\langle u,v\rangle\in\mathfrak{Q}\quad\iff\quad\forall n(Q(u_{\vert n}, v_{\vert n})).$$

Generalizing to arbitrary sentences $\sigma$ by contrast is meaningfully difficult, so I'd focus on that first. Think about coding up families of **Skolem functions** for an arbitrary $\sigma$ by individual reals. For example, suppose $\sigma$ is of the form $\forall q_1\exists q_2\forall q_3\exists q_4\tau$ with $\tau$ quantifier-free and think about $(i)$ what a family of Skolem functions for such a sentence is and how it must behave and $(ii)$ how to "bundle up" such a family of functions into a single real; this case has all the complexity of the general situation already.

Comment: Sorry I fear I may have made you think too hard. When I wrote $(\mathbb{N}, x, y)$ I was indeed referring to $(\omega, +, \cdot, <, x, y)$. I should have been more clear. I realize that the problem is significantly more difficult when I remove all the extra structure. Your answer has given me a lot to think about however and I believe I can do the easier case.

Comment: @WhyIsSetTheorySoHard Crap, never mind, you have an **if and** only if! Somehow I only saw the left-to-right direction, for which weakening the language isn't a problem; of course in a too-weak language the right-to-left direction fails. Since the left-to-right direction is the more complicated of the two (the other basically just boils down to "computable relations are definable"), I'll leave my answer up even though it only addresses that direction.

Comment: @WhyIsSetTheorySoHard I've edited to clarify this (and made a couple other minor improvements while in the area).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I mostly get it- I just need to digest it.

Comment: @WhyIsSetTheorySoHard If you need time to digest it - which is very reasonable - may I suggest unaccepting it? Accepting it may discourage others from writing additional answers, which may be helpful (especially given the partial nature of this one).